# OpenCV feature-matching algorithm suggestion for boxes on a conveyor

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection

**Overview**

I am attempting to build a prototype of a vision system that would apply pattern matching to figure out the orientation of boxes (eg. soap boxes).

**Image sample**

Below are real-time captured images of soap boxes in actual environment having two of four possible orientations. (`Front_Straight` and `Back_Inverted` orientations).

The real-time images will be very similar to these (300x200 pixels per image approx.)

[image: box_front_straight] ____ [image]

The template images will be fed to the system in prior and it has to determine the orientation of boxes moving on a conveyor. The boxes on conveyor are guided so that they can take only one of 4 possible orientations `Front_Straight`, `Front_Inverted`, `Back_Straight` and `Back_Inverted` i.e boxes cannot be angular.  The camera and the conveyor are fixed so the image size of real-time boxes is constant 300px by 200px. (I have used monochrome camera, if needed colour camera can be used too)

**Some properties of the vision system prototype:**

- Fixed constant lighting.
- The real-time image of box will be quite
  low-res as attached(300x200 per box)
- Minimal motion blur or imaging artefacts
- OpenCV C++ based coding environment.
- Intel core i5 CPU based PC will
  be used.

**Problem Statement**

I am looking for a light weight yet robust algorithm that can fairly match template image with real-time images of boxes on conveyor to extract the face and orientation. I am new to feature matching so please guide me as to which ***feature detector and matcher will be most suitable*** for this particular case. Also please let me know if it is possible to attain 97% plus accuracy using the low-res realtime image as attached.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very fortunate case, having the images with very little variation. Any feature detector should perform very well in this scenario. Since, in OpenCV, the interface is common, they are very easy to compare against each other. From my experience, ORB tends to be quite fast and with good results, but I expect SIFT/SURF to work in your case too.

I wouldn't expect the resolution to be a problem.

Comment: Then I'll do a comparison study against the three ORB,SIFT,SURF and based on their accuracy and performance will decide the most suitable detector. Thanks!